# Function to insert a node in a linked list in C

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list, function-definition

I'm trying to learn data structures in C and I'm stuck at the first function I made.
If I run this nothing happens.
I get no errors but the program doesn't print anything.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
}node;

void insert(int data, node *head){
    node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
    new_node->data = data;
    head = new_node;
}

int main(){
    node *head = NULL;
    insert(8, head);
    printf("head.data: %d\n", head->data);
}
```

But if I put the code from the function insert in the main function it works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
}node;

int main(){

    node *head = NULL;
    node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
    new_node->data = 5;
    head = new_node;
    printf("head.data: %d\n", head->data);
}
```

Do I not know how to use functions in C or what is the problem with my first code?

Comment: `head` is passed by value to the `insert` function, which means that any assignment to the local `head` variable in that function does not affect the other `head` variable in `main`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this call

```
insert(8, head);
```

the pointer `head` is passed to the function by value.

It means that the function deals with a copy of the value of the pointer.

Changing the copy within the function does not reflect on the original value of the pointer.

Either you need to pass the pointer by reference through a pointer to it or to return the new value of the pointer from the function and to assign it to the original pointer.

Also you forgot to set the data member `next` of the created node to `NULL` or more precisely to `head`.

Here you are.

```
int insert( node **head, int data )
{
    node *new_node = malloc( sizeof( node ) );
    int success = new_node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        new_node->data = data;
        new_node->next = *head;
        *head = new_node;
    }

    return success;
}
```

and the function is called like

```
insert( &head, 8 );
```

or

```
if ( !insert( &head, 8 ) )
{
    puts( "Error: not enough memory." );
}
```

Another approach is to return the new value of the pointer head from the function.

For example

```
node * insert( node *head, int data )
{
    node *new_node = malloc( sizeof( node ) );
    
    if ( new_node != NULL )
    {
        new_node->data = data;
        new_node->next = head;
    }

    return new_node;
}
```

In this case you need to use the function with caution.

For example

```
node *tmp = insert( head, 8 );
if ( tmp != NULL ) 
{
    head = tmp;
}
else
{
    puts( "Error: not enough memory." );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable `head` in `main` and the variable `head` in `insert` are two different variables. When in `insert` you assign something to that local variable, it does not affect the variable `head` in `main`.

You can solve this in different ways. One is to pass the *address* of `head` to the function, so `insert` can actually modify what is at that address:

Not your question, but you should also initialise the `next` member of `new_node`:

```
void insert(int data, node **headPtr){
    node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
    new_node->data = data;
    new_node->next = *headPtr;
    *headPtr = new_node;
}

int main(){
    node *head = NULL;
    insert(8, &head);
    printf("head.data: %d\n", head->data);
}
```